# Display selected category on the top of drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have a updateProducts page where I want to show a category drop down and within the drop down I want that `category pertaining to a particular product must be shown on the top of the list`. Which means, the drop down must show all the categories but the selected category should be shown on the top of the list.

`Code:`

```
    $pid=$_GET['id']; //getting the id from another page

    $data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid='$pid'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
        echo "<td><img src='../product_images/".$row['image']."' height='66px' width='66px' ></td>";    
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['title']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['body']."'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['cost']."'></td>";

    }

    $data2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM category");
    echo "<td><select>";
    echo "<option>Category</option>";
    while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($data2))
    {
        echo "<option>".$row2['category']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: Please see about parametrised queries

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, to keep things simple I didn't use prepared statements. Could you please help me with this problem relating to drop down?

Comment: _"category pertaining to a particular product"_ what is the relation in the `category` table?

Comment: What variable defines that particular product?

Comment: @Michel I can filter that product using `cid`(category id) but if i do that only 1 entry which is that particular category is shown.

Comment: So the category that goes on top is defined by `id = $cid`?

Comment: @Syscall product table is related to category`(cid)` and subcategory`(sid)`.

Comment: @Michel Yes exactly but then only that particular product category is shown in the drop down whereas I want the entire list to be displayed with the particular category on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First loop the results and seperate the one that goes on top, then output the select.

```
$cid=??;

$display_top;
$display_rest=array();

while($row2=mysqli_fetch_array($data2))
    {
           //if id == on_top_id set the variable on_top
        if($row2['id'] === $cid){
           $display_top= "<option>".$row2['category']."</option>";
           }
           //the rest
        else{
          $display_rest[] = "<option>".$row2['category']."</option>";
          }
    }
   //output the select
echo "<td><select>";
echo "<option>Category</option>";
   //first echo the id_on_top
echo $display_top;
   //echo the rest
echo implode('',$display_rest);
echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michel.